Corner Radius on preview layer of ImageCameraView
I've been trying to add a corner radius to the preview image being displayed in my view but nothing seems to be working. I've provided the code below. I have already applied this on the live camera and that's working, but I am struggling altering the preview image afterwards for consistency.
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct CameraView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController
    
    let cameraService: CameraService // initialize the camera service outside of the camera view
    let didFinishProcessingPhoto: (Result<AVCapturePhoto, Error>) -> ()
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        cameraService.start(delegate: context.coordinator) { error in
            if let error = error {
                didFinishProcessingPhoto(.failure(error))
                return
            }
        }
        
        let viewController = UIViewController()
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = .black
        
        // Create a UIImageView to display the captured image
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 24 // Set corner radius to 24
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true // Clip to bounds
        viewController.view.addSubview(imageView)
        
        // Add the preview layer as a sublayer to the image view's layer
        imageView.layer.addSublayer(cameraService.previewLayer)
        
        // Set the frame of the image view and preview layer
        imageView.frame = viewController.view.bounds
        cameraService.previewLayer.frame = imageView.bounds
        
        return viewController
    }

    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self, didFinishProcessingPhoto: didFinishProcessingPhoto)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) { }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
        let parent: CameraView
        private var didFinishProcessingPhoto: (Result<AVCapturePhoto, Error>) -> ()
        
        init(_ parent: CameraView, didFinishProcessingPhoto: @escaping (Result<AVCapturePhoto, Error>) -> ()) {
            self.parent = parent
            self.didFinishProcessingPhoto = didFinishProcessingPhoto
        }
        
        func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: (any Error)?) {
            if let error = error {
                didFinishProcessingPhoto(.failure(error))
                return
            }
            didFinishProcessingPhoto(.success(photo))
        }
    }
}

